# R read data set which has unequal column

Tags: r, csv, readr

I have a .csv data set which is separated by "," and has about 5,000 rows and "5" columns.

However, for some columns, the content contains also ",", for example:

> 2660,11-01-2016,70.75,05-06-2013,I,,,
>
> 4080,26-02-2016,59.36,,D

Thus, when I tried to read it with `read_delim()`, it will throw me `warnings`, but the result shall be fine, for example:

> Warning: 7 parsing failures.
>
> row # A tibble: 5 x 5 col     row   col  expected    actual                         file expected                                       actual 1   309   5 columns 8 columns 'data/my_data.csv' file 2   523   5 columns 7 columns 'data/my_data.csv' row 3   588   5 columns 8 columns 'data/my_data.csv' col 4  1661   5 columns 9 columns 'data/my_data.csv' expected 5  1877   5 columns 7 columns 'data/my_data.csv'

Is there any way for me to tackle this problem?

I guess I could use `read_Lines()` and process it one by one and then turn them into a data frame.

Do you have any other ways to deal with such a situation?

Comment: If your delimiter is comma but your data has raw, unescaped, commas then there is no way that `read.table` can make a distinction.  You can either escape columns having comma data, or as you suggest read each line manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) read.table with fill=TRUE** Using `fill=TRUE` with `read.table` results in no warnings:

```
Lines <- "2660,11-01-2016,70.75,05-06-2013,I,,,
4080,26-02-2016,59.36,,D"

# replace text = Lines with your filename    
read.table(text = Lines, sep = ",", fill = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
    V1         V2    V3         V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1 2660 11-01-2016 70.75 05-06-2013  I NA NA NA
2 4080 26-02-2016 59.36             D NA NA NA
```

**2) replace 1st 4 commas with semicolon** Another approach would be:

```
# replace textConnection(Lines) with your filename
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
for(i in 1:4) L <- sub(",", ";", L)
read.table(text = L, sep = ";")
```

giving:

```
    V1         V2    V3         V4   V5
1 2660 11-01-2016 70.75 05-06-2013 I,,,
2 4080 26-02-2016 59.36               D
```

**3) remove commas at end of lines** Another possibility is to remove commas at the end of lines. (If you are on Windows then sed is in the Rtools distribution.)

```
read.table(pipe("sed -e s/,*$// readtest.csv"), sep = ",")
```

giving:

```
    V1         V2    V3         V4 V5
1 2660 11-01-2016 70.75 05-06-2013  I
2 4080 26-02-2016 59.36             D
```

**3a) similar to (3) but without sed**

```
# replace textConnection(Lines) with your filename
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
read.table(text = sub(",*$", "", L), sep = ",")
```